# Does w3m support input type="file" form fields?

Tags: lynx, w3m

I am trying to figure out a simple way to submit a file stored on a distant Ubuntu server to an HTML form on the web. The form uses `<input type="file">` field. This seems to be [not supported by Lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.3/breakout/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html#Forms):

> Lynx does not yet support INPUTs with TYPE="file"

But can it be handled by w3m? Or any other text-based browser?

Answer (score 1):

The comment in the user's guide for Lynx is incorrect (though citing a very old version, the current guide overlooks this detail).  The file-upload feature was added about 2 years later, in [2001](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#index-v2.8.5dev.4):

```
2001-11-08 (2.8.5dev.4)
* if file-upload code is configured, suppress message that indicates it is not
  implemented, i.e., "[FILE Input] (not implemented)" -TD
```

(probably w3m does this too - it is a long time ago).